# Max with Substring/Split

Tags: sql

Unable to get max value of substrings of a column.

The columns version has values like: Sep-2018 | V.2
Out of all such values, I want to fetch all rows where max value before "|" and after "|" are present. In the data set, the desired output in version column (along with other columns) is Oct-2018 | V.6

Need to find max value for Date part i.e. Oct-2018 and for different versions like V.6

Data set:

```
  partner | region | affiliate | country | Revenue |    version     
 ---------|--------|-----------|---------|---------|---------------- 
  Alpha   | US     | USA       | USA     |     100 | Sep-2018 | V.1 
  Alpha   | US     | USA       | USA     |     568 | Sep-2018 | V.2 
  Alpha   | US     | USA       | USA     |     674 | Sep-2018 | V.6 
  Alpha   | US     | USA       | USA     |     314 | Oct-2018 | V.4 
  Alpha   | US     | USA       | USA     |     510 | Oct-2018 | V.5 
  Alpha   | US     | USA       | USA     |     309 | Oct-2018 | V.6
```

Desired Result:

```
Alpha   US  USA USA 309 Oct-2018 | V.6
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Why aren't the date components stored in an orderable format, YYYY-MM?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to CYMD for sortation
Then add the second value for handling ties

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL, the below script should work; 1st ORDER BY gets latest date, 2nd ORDER BY gets maximum version value.

```
select top 1 * 
from [tablename]
order by 
    convert(date, '01-'+SUBSTRING([version], 1, charindex('|', [version]) - 2)) DESC,
    SUBSTRING([version], charindex('|', [version]) + 3, LEN([version])) DESC
```

Comment: The query gives me this error-" column date doesn't exist"

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  My answer was specific to MS SQL, but the concept of date conversion would work with other RDBMS.

Comment: Can you please share you email id?

Comment: I am using Redshift and i tried extracting max values from V.1, V.2, V.3., etc using the query mentioned below:

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Redshift syntax so I'm afraid I can't be of much more help.  The issue you're having does seem to be specific to the syntax of Redshift, or you're not using a conversion function where you should be.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Redshift and I tried extracting max values from V.1, V.2, V.3., etc using the query mentioned below:                                                                                  ***select * from example where cast(substring(version,regexp_instr(version,'.')+1) as decimal)
= (select max(cast(substring(version,regexp_instr(version,'.')+1) as decimal)) from example)***
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 But got this error:  Unable to complete action
[Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState XX000] ERROR:  Invalid digit, Value 'e', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
DETAIL:

---

error:  Invalid digit, Value 'e', Pos 0, Type: Integer 
 code:      1207
 context:   ep-2018 | V.3
 query:     18804464
 location:  :0
 process:   query1_593_18804464 [pid=0]

---

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName
WHERE Version in (SELECT distinct MAX(Version) FROM YourTableName GROUP BY partner);
```